# Place DIV in new column when end of page reached

Tags: html, css

I have some DIVs on a page. How can I make the DIVs create a new column on the right when the bottom of the page is reached. So I have some small fixed height DIVs with images inside them. After every DIV, there is a line and then the next div and so on. On smaller displays, the screen requires scrolling to see the DIVs. So I added `overflow: hidden` to the body, to disable the scrolling. Now the DIVs at the very bottom are cut out, so I want the DIVs that are cut out, to create a new column to the right.

**Example:** [image: picture].

```css
body {
overflow: hidden;}
#icon {
background: #000;
color:#fff;
height:50px;
width:50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id=icon>1</div><br>
<div id=icon>2</div><br>
<div id=icon>3</div><br>
<div id=icon>4</div><br>
<div id=icon>5</div><br>
<div id=icon>6</div><br>
<div id=icon>7</div><br>
<div id=icon>8</div><br>
<div id=icon>9</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/a3os9fmc/

Comment: Indeed, I thought that what you were looking for is something changes according to the height, kind of dynamic rather than fixed

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Yeah, the page is supposed to dynamic on all screen sizes

Comment: you may want to remove `align-content: flex-start;` to have a different result. Also you may consider checking browsers support or flexbox http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox , which is still better than css column or grid but just to be sure about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of solutions to this and all run into polyfill issues. Columns are notorious for this.

A good option with decent coverage is to use flexboxes. Flexboxes were pretty much made for this kind of stuff.

Wrap all the `divs` in another div (i used `section`) and give the wrapping container some flexbox rules:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh; /*the height will need to be customized*/
  width: 50px;
}

#icon {
  background: #000;
  color:#fff;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrap">
    <div id=icon>1</div><br>
    <div id=icon>2</div><br>
    <div id=icon>3</div><br>
    <div id=icon>4</div><br>
    <div id=icon>5</div><br>
    <div id=icon>6</div><br>
    <div id=icon>7</div><br>
    <div id=icon>8</div><br>
    <div id=icon>9</div>
</section>
```

You'll need to give height and width rules to the wrapper, however. If it's in another container with a set height, you should be able to give it `height: 100%` and it will reach the bottom of the page.

Word of warning: `columns` and `flexboxes` are notorious for having cross-browser compatability issues, though mobile browsers are somewhat better at this. A good solution is to use a library with a focus on responsive or mobile design, like Bootstrap or SpaceBase (though the latter is a SASS library)

Answer (score 1):

@samuel-denty are you looking for CSS Columns ?

here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zk7578vj/
try using `class` (.) icon instead of `id` (#) on css, like this:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-columns: 50px 2;
    -moz-columns: 50px 2;
    columns: 50px 2;
}
.icon {
    background: #000;
    color:#fff;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}


<body>
    <div class="icon">1</div><br>
    <div class="icon">2</div><br>
    <div class="icon">3</div><br>
    <div class="icon">4</div><br>
    <div class="icon">5</div><br>
    <div class="icon">6</div><br>
    <div class="icon">7</div><br>
    <div class="icon">8</div><br>
    <div class="icon">9</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tested this method, it works but it didn't automatically adjust when zoomed in or out